# What is the proper jargon to refer to a variable wrapped inside a function closure?

Tags: javascript, closures, jargon

In JavaScript, there is no such thing as a "private" variable.  In order to achieve encapsulation and information hiding in JavaScript, I can wrap a variable inside a function closure, like so:

```
var counter = (function() {    
    var i = 0;
    var fn = {};
    fn.increment = function() { i++; };
    fn.get = function() { return i; };
    return fn;
{)();    
counter.increment();
counter.increment();
alert(counter.get()); // alerts '2'
```

Since I don't call `i` a private variable in JavaScript, what do I call it?

Comment: `s/fn/counter/` outside of the outer anonymous function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) they're called "upvalues".

> A closure allows a function to access variables outside its immediate
>   lexical scope. An upvalue is a free variable that has been bound
>   (closed over) with a closure. The closure is said to "close over" its
>   upvalues.

Although it's probably better to wrongly call them private variables so people will understand what you mean.

Comment: You could also just call it a free variable